# TORQUE SERVER : How to avoid job killing when memory exceed?

Tags: memory, config, pbs, torque

I install a Torque server, I add a node and it works fine.

But I don't understand how job configuration work.

Here is my job configuration: "#PBS -l vmem=128mb", my job use more memory so the Torque server kill the process. If I increase the value, it works well.

pvmem = Maximum amount of virtual memory used by any single process in the job. (Ignored on Unicos.)

There is a server configuration to let process running when they exceed memory but I didn't find this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this, add

```
$ignvmem true
```

to your mom's config file. There are similar parameters for mem, walltime, and cputime if you wish to use them. They are documented [here.](http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/torque/help.htm#topics/12-appendices/nodeManagerConfig.htm?TocPath=Appendices%7CAppendix%20C%3a%20Node%20manager%20%28MOM%29%20configuration%7C_____0)